# when i want to consume my web service occur run time error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, web-services, ios4

i upload a web service on my website's server `www.example.com/webservice/SampleService.asmx` and the method that i want to connect to it is `GetAllUserInfo`, i use below code for consume this web service but occur runtime error,can anybody help me to consume this web service

- I test this web service and work properly on visual studio

> ```
> NSString *soapMsg =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"
> "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="
>  "\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" "  
>  "xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" "
>  "xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">"   
>  "<soap:Body>"     
>  "<GetAllUserInfo xmlns=\"http://www.example.com/\">" 
>  "</GetAllUserInfo>"   
>  "</soap:Body>"    
>  "</soap:Envelope>"];
>
> NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.example.com/SampleService.asmx"];              
>
> NSMutableURLRequest *req = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
>
> NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [soapMsg length]];                  
> [req addValue:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];               
> [req addValue:@"http://www.example.com/GetAllUserInfo" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
>
> [req addValue:msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];          
> [req setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];                
> [req setHTTPBody:[soapMsg dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
> ```

Comment: What's the error? Is it a secret?

Comment: what's the real return xml message? Would you post it here? Also, have you tried the Hello World sample SOAP web service Microsoft provided?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the full error message with this:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    NSLog(@"data: %.*s", [data length], [data bytes]);
}
```

Comment: The error is here:

    [req addValue:@"http://www.example.com/webservices/GetAllUserInfo" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];

You are passing a SOAPAction parameter in the HTTP request that does not match what the service is expecting. Are you including the directory in your SOAPAction parameter?

Comment: Is your value example.com/webservices/GetAllUserInfo or example.com/GetAllUserInfo? It should be the latter.

Comment: You can also get this if you call the wrong method. For example, you can get this error if you call SampleService1.asmx for method GetAllUserInfo, instead of calling SampleService2.asmx. Hard to troubleshoot without seeing the actual ASMX.

Comment: please delete your answer that i delete this question